# Appending tuple to a buffer in Scala

Tags: scala, scala-collections

In Scala,

```
test("Appending a tuple to a Buffer"){
    val buffer = ArrayBuffer[Int]()
    val aTuple = (2, 3)
    println(buffer += (2, 3))  // Result : ArrayBuffer(2, 3)
    println(buffer += aTuple )  // doesn't compile
}
```

Why does line

```
println(buffer += (2, 3))
```

work, but  line

```
println(buffer += aTuple )
```

not compile ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because you are not adding a `Tuple`, you are calling the `+=` method with two parameters:

```
buffer += (3, 4)
// is equivalent here to
buffer.+=(3, 4)
```

And that method [is defined](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer) both with varargs and without, and adds to the buffer everything it is given:

```
def +=(elem: A): ArrayBuffer.this.type 
def +=(elem1: A, elem2: A, elems: A*): ArrayBuffer.this.type
```